# How to log qunit test results to a file

Tags: javascript, xml, ant, phantomjs, qunit

We are using qunit to write test cases for JavaScript. Test cases are getting passed, but we are not able to write the test result to a xml file. We run the tests using Ant.

In dev environment it actually needs to be picked up by jenkins. As per my understanding Jenkins will see the results in output xml for marking build as success/failure.

Currently I am using the following entries in build.xml

```
<arg line="--qunit ${basedir}/WebContent/js/qunit/qunit-1.14.0.js --tests ${basedir}/WebContent/js --junit ${basedir}/qunit-results.xml"/>
```

Thanks in advance for suggestions